# Extreme Value Theory: GPD application to returns, not losses (PnL)?

Tags: pareto-distribution

As it is often presented, Extreme Value Theory (EVT) is applied to financial losses (and gains as well, but always focusing in the tails). By EVT, I especially refer to:

1) Mean excess plot to find an appropriate threshold
2) Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD) to fit to the data in the tail, beyond the estimated threshold in 1).

My question is: does it make sense to apply steps 1) and 2) to daily (arithmetic) returns, and not to PnL?

I have also seen some cases where steps 1) and 2) are applied to the residuals of a fitted model, e.g. ARMA or GARCH.

Which approach is the best?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for downvote?!?!

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you mean by "apply steps 1) and 2) to daily (arithmetic) returns, and not to losses?". Losses are one side of the return distribution. Do you mean applying EVT to the other side of the distribution, the wins?

Comment: @Ami44 No, I mean PnL... Well spotted, I will correct it for clarity.

Comment: The "return" is just the profit or loss on an initial investment of 1.00. So it seems to me you are making a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why it should not be possible to apply peak-over-threshold to the returns.

Also see page 15 of
https://www.soa.org/library/newsletters/risk-management-newsletter/2009/september/jrm-2009-iss17-levine.pdf

They use EVT on returns.